# React - Use a component as a <tr> for a table

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react ans I am creating a dashboard using react. This is what I am getting with pure `html` table:

[image]

And this is what I got when I am passing a component as a `<tr>` inside my table. All the data from `User.js` is returning within one column instead of 4.

[image]

**User.js**

```
function User(props){
    return (

        <tr>    
            <td>{props.email}</td>
            <td>{props.registration}</td>
            <td>{props.status}</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { 
          email: "pierre-alexandre@gmail.com",
          registration: "2020-10-25",
          status: "active"
        },
        [...]
      ],
      searchEmail: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    let filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter((user) => {
      return user.email
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(this.state.searchEmail.toLowerCase());
    });
    return (
      <div>
        [...]
            <div class="dashboard-content">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Registration Date</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Other</th>
                </tr>
                <UserList filteredUsers={filteredUsers} />
              </table>
          [...]
```

**UserList.js**

```
function UserList (props) {
    let users = props.filteredUsers.map((user, i)=> {
        return <User key={i} email={user.email} registration={user.registration} status={user.status}/>
    })
    if(users.length < 1){
        return <div>No users found. {props.placeholder}
        Make sure that the email is spelled and formatted correctly</div>
    }

    return <div>
        {users}
    </div>
}

export default UserList
```

*update: i tried kboul solution (comment) but it's not working;*

[image]

Comment: Inspect your DOM. It looks like you insert a `div`.

Comment: Correct! But on my `User.js` I am returning a `<tr>` and not a div, how can I fix it?

Comment: Use one row `tr` per element. `<><tr><td>{props.email}</td></tr><tr><td>{props.registration}</td></tr></> ... `goes on.... Right now you put everything in one row.

Comment: does not work. I can not compile "JSX expressions must have one parent element"

Comment: Use `<> </>` in the beginning to wrap `tr`s

Comment: Compiling but retuning a making things worst, i updated my post witht he result

Comment: can you show the code of User? basically, User should return one tr with td's in it per iteration, my guess is your returning one div with one tr in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore what I wrote in the comments. It was a wrong guess. I think you can make it simpler. Also you display a message inside a table in case your data is of 0 length so you get different kind of warnings / errors in the console.

In my opinion you do not need `UserList`. You only need `User`.

You can achieve what you want with the following code:

```
<div className="dashboard-content">
        {filteredUsers.length > 0 ? (
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Registration Date</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>Other</td>
              </tr>
              {filteredUsers.map((user, i) => {
                return <User key={i} user={user} />;
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        ) : (
          <div>
            No users found. Make sure that the email is spelled and formatted
            correctly
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
```

Iterate over `filteredUsers` and then return a User comp by passing only the user object. If the array is of 0 length return the message.

Your user comp will look like this, similar to what you had:

```
function User({ user }) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{user.email}</td>
      <td>{user.registration}</td>
      <td>{user.status}</td>
      <td>{user.other}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-use-a-component-as-a-tr-for-a-table-bjsz9?file=/src/User.jsx:43-225)